# Server CPU only getting 1.5 to 2.5 KH/s

Tags: mining

My miner output:

```
HASHRATE REPORT - CPU
| ID |    10s |    60s |    15m | ID |    10s |    60s |    15m |
|  0 |  396.8 |  394.6 |  393.2 |  1 |  313.1 |  311.7 |  310.8 |
|  2 |  397.3 |  394.9 |  393.7 |  3 |  397.0 |  394.9 |  393.5 |
|  4 |  387.9 |  385.6 |  384.4 |  5 |  397.3 |  394.9 |  393.6 |
Totals (CPU):  2289.3 2276.5 2269.1 H/s
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Totals (ALL):   2289.3 2276.5 2269.1 H/s
Highest:  2295.9 H/s
```

I have an "intel(R) Xeon(R) silver 4210 CPU : 2.20GHz" and have 20 cores showing in the device manager.

How come its mining slower than my i5?

Answer (score 0):

You may well have 10 cores (or 20 threads), but you only have enough *cache* for 5 threads to mine, and your output is only showing 3 threads mining.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I go about increasing this hash rate? Getting the program to use 5 threads?

Comment: "How would I go about increasing this hash rate?" correctly configure to only use 5 (or 6) threads; or remove all your CPU config and let XMRig auto-generate the correct config for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but please update your post with your config.json file, at least the CPU section of it. That could allow us to better help you.

What I'm thinking that issue may be, though, is if copied the config.json file over from your i5. **Try creating a new config.json file at the [XMRig wizard](https://xmrig.com/wizard) and report back.**

Edit: Looks like [@jtgrassie](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/7493/jtgrassie) is correct, for the not enough cache part, at least. You are able to mine on only 6 threads because your CPU doesn't have enough L3 cache. The [XMRig RandomX Optimization Guide](https://xmrig.com/docs/miner/randomx-optimization-guide) says...

> Memory size requirements
>
> - 2080 MB per NUMA node for dataset, 1 NUMA node usually equal to 1 CPU socket, the miner show number of nodes on startup.
> - 256 MB for cache on first NUMA node.
> - 256 KB of L2 cache and **2 MB of L3 cache per 1 mining thread**.

**Your CPU only has 13.75 MB of L3 cache, and since 2 MB are needed per thread, you only have enough cache for 6 threads.**

Note: It says 0-5 because computers count from 0.